# can i store asp.net session state in azure documentdb?

Tags: asp.net, azure, session, azure-cosmosdb

I want to know if I can store asp.net session state in azure documentdb?
I remember there was a special store provider for appfabric cache to store session state (configured in web.config), and I was wondering if I can do the same with documentdb.
I assume that the consistency of the collection holding the session state would have to be defined as 'strong consistency', am I right?
what is the best way to store session state in azure documentdb?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if I can store asp.net session state in azure documentdb? I remember there was a special store provider for appfabric cache to store session state (configured in web.config), and I was wondering if I can do the same with documentdb.

Firstly, I find [this article](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/documentdb-for-sessions/) that explained using Azure DocumentDB as session state store, but the information is not enough for me to create a working sample, I get error that is caused by assembly `Sitecore.SessionProvider` and it's dependencies issues.

Secondly, if possible, you can try to implement a custom session-state store provider to store session-state information in Azure DocumentDB. You can refer to "[Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx)" to create a class that inherits the SessionStateStoreProviderBase abstract class and implement the required members of the ProviderBase class.

Besides, [Azure Redis Cache provides a session state provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider), we can use to store session state in a cache rather than in-memory or in a SQL Server database. If you can not find any Azure DocumentDB session state providers and do not want to implement your own session-state store provider, you can try to use RedisSessionStateProvider.

Comment: Thank you fred, that article says it is not for the session store nor it is supported. I know about the redis solution, I was looking at a different solution. currently I don't think I will implement a session state store provider by myself, I thought that maybe Microsoft has built one or maybe they will make one in the near future.

Comment: ``currently I don't think I will implement a session state store provider by myself, I thought that maybe Microsoft has built one or maybe they will make one in the near future.`` You can give a feedback on [Azure Cosmos DB Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

Comment: Thanks Fred, that's a good idea. i added a feedback on that link as a result of your comment. Thank you (-: